# What kind of Certifcate and Provisioning Profile is needed for an iOS Apple TestFlight release?

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight, beta

I'm planning to release a beta version of my iPhone app on iOS 8 devices through the new Apple TestFlight app.
What kind of Certifcate and Provisioning Profile is needed for that? Do I need a *Production* certificate and *Distribution* provisioning profile?

Available are these:

```
Certificate:
- Pending
- Development
- Production

Provisioning Profile:
- Development
- Distribution
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I believe you need a Production certificate with a Distribution profile for "App Store". I just submit my app which is now in review for external beta testers.  The first time I submit the app I was using an Ad Hoc profile as we always did while using the original Testflight.  That profile caused the app to be rejected before it even got to the review processes.  Once I changed to using an App Store profile it passed into the review process.  So, Production cert, Distribution App Store provisioning profile worked for me.

The [Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) has some information on beta testing options for ios.  It discusses both Ad Hoc and iTunes connect distribution.

You can also [check out this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224), which goes through the processes using xcode to submit your build for testing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks Tim, that helps a lot! :) Do you have an idea how long the review process for a beta release takes? Same as for an official App Store release?

Comment: I actually just got back my email saying it passed review and is ready for beta testing.  I submit the app last Wed (11/26) and got my acceptance today (12/2).  However that was over Thanksgiving holiday and a weekend.  It also probably depends on their workload.  I have heard however someone having it done as little as 12 hours, and others a lot longer.

Answer (score 59):

The Apple Technical Note [TN2407](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2407/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014991-CH1-RECOMMENDED_WORKFLOWS-SUBMITTING_YOUR_APP_FOR_PUBLISHING_TO_TESTFLIGHT) has a section titled "Submitting your app for publishing to TestFlight" and in this section Apple says:

> TestFlight apps submitted to iTunesConnect need to be signed with an App Store Distribution Profile. TestFlight no longer accepts apps submitted with an Ad Hoc profile.

So the situation is now unambiguous: you need a production certificate for the app, and an App Store distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: What happens with the app if the distribution profile expires?

Answer (score 29):

You should use the following types of certificate and provisioning profile:

```
Certificate:
- Production (iOS Distribution)

Provisioning Profile:
- Distribution (App Store)
```

You should use an **App Store Distribution** Provisioning Profile to upload to Apple TestFlight:

[image: Create a Provisioning Profile]

When you go through the process of creating the Provisioning Profile, it will filter your Certificates to only allow **iOS Distribution** certificates.

[image: Create a Certificate]

Comment: pictures make stack overflow great

Comment: s this the case still with testflight, regarding the app needs to be a Distrubuted provision profile ?