# Cannot distribute development app to Testflight due to iCloud component

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, testflight, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to upload app to testflight via Appcenter, and I have icloud document storage functionality therefore I have added following enlistement into enlistement.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <array>
        <string>CloudKit</string>
        <string>CloudDocuments</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.com.company.appname</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I followed this tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2415/_index.html
[image]

But when I try to push release to itunes connect to testflight I get this error:

> DEBUG [2018-04-24 06:34:46.43]: [Transporter]: DBG-X: parameter
>   ErrorMessage = ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements.
>   Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements
>   that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'Development' for
>   key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' in
>   'Payload/App.MobileApp.iOS.app/App.MobileApp.iOS' is not supported."

My certificate distribution and provision profile are set to production as suggested here: [What kind of Certifcate and Provisioning Profile is needed for an iOS Apple TestFlight release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201359/what-kind-of-certifcate-and-provisioning-profile-is-needed-for-an-ios-apple-test).

Comment: But it's complaining about the section above that. Maybe you should remove `<string>Development</string>`

Comment: I don't have it in my document at all

Comment: Yes, it is in the array for the key mentioned in the error: `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment`.  You have two entries in the array: one is Production, one is Development.  Delete the line that @valdetero mentioned. Please note that you are highlighting the entries for com.apple.developer.icloud-container-**identifiers**, not com.apple.developer.icloud-container-**environment** as the error states.

Comment: second image you see is not my document.. all i have in enlistement.plist is first xml

Answer (score 3):

I spent tons of hours trying to figure it out how to solve this on App Center and I came with a workaround.

Define a key in your Entitlement with this name:
`com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment`

which will contain an array with a string value:
`Production`

Your Entitlement will look something like this:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
<array>
    <string>Production</string>
</array>
```

Make sure your build definition is on Release or AppStore mode and you have your correct Entitlements in your provisioning profile and you should be good.

Explanation:
I think the process to check your Entitlements through AppCenter is getting both values when it gets the environments available for your build, instead of using a process like the Xcode / VS Studio / Itunes Connect uses when it validates your provisioning profile environment through Apples Developer Account’s API.

Hope this works to you.